# Are Windows 10 editions (Home/Pro) key-based or installation-based?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, windows-installer, windows-activation, windows-edition

I'd built a new PC and purchased a Windows 10 Home edition activation key. During the Windows 10 ISO file creation, I didn't see any options to create installation files for Home or Pro edition, just simply "Windows 10" (I created the ISO on my Windows 10 Pro laptop). So basically now I have an ISO for "Windows 10" and unspecified edition. My guess is that the edition will be based on the key I will use to activate it later (which is Home edition), am I correct? (This is my first question)

Second question: The thing is that, I don't have a DVD to write the ISO on, and no suitable removable flash drive to do USB installation. However, I have a Windows 10 installation DVD that my dad burned it for me 3 years ago (along with a Pro edition key he gave me, which I'm using on my laptop). So, can I use that DVD to install Windows 10 Home on my newly built PC? Because I'm not sure at the time of creation (around late 2017), if the installation files on the DVD is tied to one edition (i.e. Pro edition), or it has always been generic "Windows 10" and the edition would be decided by the activation key later.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically now I have an ISO for "Windows 10" and unspecified edition.

The Media Creation Tool created a unified single ISO that contains both Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional.  This has been the case for nearly 4 years now.

You really should consider the small expense to create a new installation disk. You will spend a considerable amount of time having to update your system if use an installation disk from 3 years ago.

> My guess is that the edition will be based on the key I will use to activate it later (which is Home edition), am I correct?

During the installation process you will be promoted for your Windows 10 license key.  You will want to enter the retail Windows 10 Home license key at this time.

If the license key is not a Retail license key then the installation cannot be activated.

> All I'm afraid of is that the DVD is created at around late 2017 (therefore could be Windows version 1703 or 1709) so it might be tied to a specific Windows 10 edition, instead of the "generic" Windows 10 I've just downloaded today.

What you describe doesn’t exist, even if the installation media is for an older version of Windows 10, your retail license to Windows 10 Home absolutely will work provided the .WIM image contains Windows 10 Home. The age of the ISO isn’t a concern you should have.

You can confirm that is the case by using *Get-WimInfo* on the .WIM image contained on the disk.

```
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:F:\sources\install.wim /index:1
```

> Granted you can skip the key activation; however, you will still not be able to use the newer key when you finally decide to activate.

You absolutely can install Windows 10 with a generic license key, and once it’s installed, change the license key so it can be activated. This of course isn’t necessary since you already have a retail Windows 10 license key

> So, can I use that DVD to install Windows 10 Home on my newly built PC?

Yes

> Because I'm not sure at the time of creation (around late 2017), if the installation files on the DVD is tied to one edition (i.e. Pro edition), or it has always been generic "Windows 10" and the edition would be decided by the activation key later.

It doesn’t matter when it was made, Windows once it has been installed, will automatically update to the current version.  You could install 1507 and upgrade that to 20H2 if you wanted.

Comment: I am just curious to see if I am missing something. Would there not be a problem in this case since the DVD WIN OS is a “pro” version and the ISO and newer key is a “Home” version?

Comment: @JohnG - A Windows 10 ISO can contain multiple versions of Windows 10.  Microsoft only provides ISOs that contains multiple versions on their website.  Only regional exclusive ISOs are separate (Single Language) and/or Education and Enterprise. **There is a reason I provided a command to verify which images are contained on the disk.**